# Does netcat support proxy authentication?

Tags: netcat

How to deal with this:

```
nc: Proxy error: "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
```

`nc` has a `-P` option for proxy username, but what's for password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what Netcat variant you're using, but presuming it's OpenBSD's netcat, the proxy authentication behavior, as of version 1.105, should have you prompted on the commandline for a password:

`"Proxy password for %s@%s: "` is the prompt, with proxy username & proxy password applied for the string format inputs.